# Get data from database and use in interface in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-sqlite, android-database

I am using **Urls** class(code given below) to set different urls I want to use in my app

```
    public interface Urls {
        public String SERVER_BASE_URL = "http://webaddress.com/";
    public String URL_DIRECT =SERVER_BASE_URL + "token.php";
        public String URL_DIRECT2= SERVER_BASE_URL + "token2.php";
        public String URL_DIRECT3= SERVER_BASE_URL + "token3.php";
    }
```

Now I want to change the value of `SERVER_BASE_URL` from static value to a value from my database. The IP address is correctly stored in the database. For this I use the basic code as I need this page appear only once to store the IP address.

```
mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("IP", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS value1(ipaddress VARCHAR);");
String a = ip.getText().toString();
mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO value1 VALUES('" + a + "');");
```

I am getting the correct IP from database using this code

```
Cursor resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("Select * from value1", null);
                resultSet.moveToFirst();
                address = resultSet.getString(0);
```

But I don't know how to set this IP to the `SERVER_BASE_URL` programmatically.
Or I want to get value from database on each activity ???
Please help!!!!

Comment: where are you calling your php scripts ?

Comment: Almost all pages are loading using the data from Json.

Comment: so you will be calling the script that will fetch the base url first and then call the actual script ? correct ?

Comment: Actually not. I am calling http://webaddress.com/token.php as first script. The `SERVER_BASE_URL ` is same for all scripts. Thats why I used like this

Comment: so want to call something like ipaddress/token.php

Comment: you are getting the ip address from server ?

Comment: no. user is entering the ip initially when the app is first installed.

Comment: does every time user enter the ip address manually or at only once when the app is installed and open for the first time

Comment: only once when the app is first opened. Then that value is saved in database.

Comment: then you can make use of shared preference.

Comment: How??? Can you explain?

Comment: i will explain in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

App first launch

**InputActivity**

XML:

```
<EditText
android:id = "@+id/ip_address_text"
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:hint = "Enter your IP Address"
android:inputType = "text"/>

<Button
android:id = "@+id/button_submit"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:text = "SUBMIT"/>
```

Java:

```
EditText ipText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_address_text); 
Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
SharedPreference sp = getSharedPreferences("ANY NAME FOR PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.edit().putString("ip_address", ipText.getText().toString()).apply();
      }
    });
```

**Script Calling Activity**

Java:

Before hitting the server.

```
SharedPreference sp = getSharedPreferences("ANY NAME FOR PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String ipAddress = sp.getString("ip_address", "Default value");
```

Updated code

```
public interface Urls {
SharedPreference sp = getSharedPreferences("ANY NAME FOR PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    public String SERVER_BASE_URL = sp.getString("ip_address", "Default value");
    public String URL_DIRECT =SERVER_BASE_URL + "token.php";
    public String URL_DIRECT2= SERVER_BASE_URL + "token2.php";
    public String URL_DIRECT3= SERVER_BASE_URL + "token3.php";
    }
```

and use the variable url to hit the server.

> Your question is not pointing to the particular part instead asking
>   for whole implementation. Try to narrow your issue which will be
>   helpful for the solvers to answer rather than asking for the entire
>   code for implementation.

Good Luck!!

Reference links to use

[Shared Preferences 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

[Shared Preferences 2](http://androidexample.com/Android_SharedPreferences_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=126&aaid=146)

Comment: Thanks Ragu Swaminathan. Let me try it.

Comment: Also Ragu Swaminathan I dont need the whole code. I need to get the idea which can be implemented here correctly.   Also I actually want to change the value in `Urls` class so that I only need to call `URL_DIRECT` or `URL_DIRECT2` in every activity instead of calling `String url = ipAddress+"token2.php"`;

Comment: kindly post your url code. will me to answer better for you.

Comment: I am saying about Urls (interface class) given in my question.